# Errata in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology Exercise 1.3.28?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Hatcher's Algebraic Topology Exercise 1.3.28 is :

**Exercise 1.3.28.** Show that for a covering space action of a group $G$ on a simply-connected space $Y$, $\pi_1(Y/G)$ is isomorphic to $G$. [If $Y$ is locally is path-connected, this is a special case of part (b) of Proposition 1.40.]

Proposition 1.40 is :

**Proposition 1.40.** Given a covering space action of a group $G$ on a space $Y$,

(a) The quotient map $p : Y \to Y/G$ is a normal covering space.

(b) $G$ is the group of deck transformations of the covering space if $Y$ is path-connected.

(c) $G$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y/G)/p_*(\pi_1(Y))$ if $Y$ is path-connected and locally path-connected.

I think Exercise 1.3.28 is a special case of part (c) of Proposition 1.40, not (b). But there is no mention in the errata list in Hatcher's homepage : http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/ .
Am I wrong?

Comment: Your interpretation seems correct to me, since $p_*(\pi_1(Y))$ is going to be trivial if $Y$ is simply-connected. Probably just missing from the errata. (If you're studying for your algebraic topology midterms too right now, good luck!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

You are right. Part (b) does not allow to conlude that $G \approx \pi_1(Y/G)$.